# iPhone - Objective-C - Memory Leak with initWithArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, autorelease

I am using the code below to set my two `NSArray` ivars:

The issue is, I keep getting a memory leak on the following lines:

```
followingFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friend.Following];
followerFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friend.Followers];
```

Is this not the correct way to set ivars from an existing `NSArray` of items? Any help would be appreciated. I've also tried to `autorelease` the above two lines, but when I actually access them in another method I get an error that they've already been released.

I have included my Interface and Implementation code below:

Interface .h:

```
NSArray *followingFriendsArray;
NSArray *followerFriendsArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *followingFriendsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *followerFriendsArray;
```

Implementation .m:

```
- (void)handlerGetFollowingInformation:(id)value {
    BOOL success = [Utility checkWebServiceErrors:value controller:self.navigationController];

    if (success) {
        Friend *friend = (Friend *)value;

        followingFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friend.Following];
        followerFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friend.Followers];
    }
}
```

This is how I need to access the arrays:

```
- (void)followersButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    FollowingVC *fvc = [[FollowingVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FollowingViewController" bundle:nil];

    fvc.friends = followerFriendsArray;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];
    [fvc release];
}
```

I release my two ivars in the following way as per usual:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.followingFriendsArray = nil;
    self.followerFriendsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [followingFriendsArray release];
    [followerFriendsArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I mean the code works just fine, it's just that I'm concerned about said memory leaks when I run the "Leaks" performance tool.

Comment: Were do you release those 2 arrays? and BTW why do you use mutable arrays?

Comment: I have changed them to be NSArray's. I release them in the usual dealloc way within the View Controller as per usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRD is right that the arrays are not released inside the handlerGeFollowingInformation method but the fix is maybe overkill. What you need to do is to use **self.** so that the setter method is called which does that automatically. You could should look like this:

```
- (void)handlerGetFollowingInformation:(id)value {
    BOOL success = [Utility checkWebServiceErrors:value controller:self.navigationController];

    if (success) {
        Friend *friend = (Friend *)value;

        self.followingFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friend.Following];
        self.followerFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friend.Followers];
    }
}
```

Easy fix but hard to spot and I ran into this issue over and over again especially when I started to dealloc are the properties.

-Andy

Comment: ATTENTION: sorry forgot to spot that you need to release the Array as well or you could use [NSArray arrayWithArray:find.Following] to create your array.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I think I'm going to go with [NSArray arrayWithArray:] because it's so much easier than having to worry about releasing the array. Are there any drawbacks or issues with doing it that way? I assume it's just like initialising an array using [NSArray array] am I right?

Comment: If I am not mistaken [NSArray array*] methods are the same as the [[[NSArray alloc] init*]autorelease] except that you don't have to worry about the memory management when you create them (the * means any additional name like 'WithArray'). There are many objects that provide such static convenience methods like NSDictionary etc and I like them too. But then again remember to use "self." when you want to use the property setter method.

Answer (score 3):

OK

you should not use autorelease in this case, but you have to release the arrays by calling :

```
[followingFriendsArray release];
[followerFriendsArray release];
```

you can do it:

1. when you don't need to use them any more.
2. in the dealloc method in your .m file.

option 2looks like that -

```
- (void)dealloc {
[followingFriendsArray release];
[followerFriendsArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

BTW -
if you don't manipulate the arrays after creating them (add / remove objects) you should use an immutable array (NSArray).
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm releasing them in the dealloc method as per usual. I'm just trying to fix the memory leaks occurring in the "Leaks Profiler". Is it okay that they're recorded as leaks as long as I release them in dealloc? This is what I'm confused about.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `handlerGetFollowingInformation` is assigning new values to `followingFriendsArray` and `followerFriendsArray` without releasing the previous contents. If you call this method more than once on the same instance you will leak.